# How to obtain signature from the cborhex? If i have simple-tx.signed

Tags: cardano-cli, cbor

```
{
    "type": "Witnessed Tx BabbageEra",
    "description": "Ledger Cddl Format",
    "cborHex": "84a3008182582088921ae2626e"
}
```

This is just an example

Comment: Is that the output from an actual file? The hex is not valid CBOR.

Answer (score 0):

First off, when analyzing CBOR data, cbor.me is your friend. Paste in the CBOR hex string and let it show you the structure.

In the witness files that I've worked with, the structure is as follows:

```
82                           # array(2)
  00                         # unsigned(0)
  82                         # array(2)
    58 20                    # bytes(32)
      71...60                # <- This is the vkey bytes
    58 40                    # bytes(64)
      6C...0F                # <- This is the signature bytes
```